# setting up bind to work with nsupdate (SERVFAIL)

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, dynamic-dns, ddns

I'm trying to update my DNS-Server dynamically using nsupdate.

## Prerequisite

I'm using Debian 6 on my DNS-Server and Debian 4 on my client.

I created a public/private key pair using:

```
dnssec-keygen -C -a HMAC-MD5 -b 512 -n USER sub.example.com.
```

I then edited my *named.conf.local* to contain my public key and the new zone i wish to update. It now looks like this (note: I also tried *allow-update { any; };* without success):

```
zone "example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/primary/example.com";
        notify yes;
        allow-update { none; };
        allow-query { any; };
};

zone "sub.example.com" {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/primary/sub.example.com";
        notify yes;
        allow-update { key "sub.example.com."; };
        allow-query { any; };
};

key sub.example.com. {
        algorithm HMAC-MD5;
        secret "xxxx xxxx";
};
```

Next, I copied the private key file (*key.private*) to another server I want to update the zone from. I also created a textfile (*update*) on this server which contained the update information (note: I tried toying around with this stuff too. no success):

```
server example.com
zone sub.example.com
update add sub.example.com. 86400 A 10.10.10.1
show
send
```

Now I'm trying to update the zone using:

```
nsupdate -k key.private -v update
```

## The Problem

Said command gives me the following output:

```
Outgoing update query:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: UPDATE, status: NOERROR, id:      0
;; flags: ; ZONE: 0, PREREQ: 0, UPDATE: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; ZONE SECTION:
;sub.example.com.       IN  SOA

;; UPDATE SECTION:
sub.example.com.    86400   IN  A   10.10.10.1

update failed: SERVFAIL
```

named debug Level 3 gives me the following information when I issue the nsupdate command on the remote server (note: I obfuscated the client IP):

```
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.977 client X.X.X.X#33182: new TCP connection
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.977 client X.X.X.X#33182: replace
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 clientmgr @0x2ada3c7ee760: createclients
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 clientmgr @0x2ada3c7ee760: recycle
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client @0x2ada475f1120: accept
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: read
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: TCP request
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: request has valid signature
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: recursion not available
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: update
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: send
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.978 client X.X.X.X#33182: sendto
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.979 client X.X.X.X#33182: senddone
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.979 client X.X.X.X#33182: next
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.979 client X.X.X.X#33182: endrequest
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.979 client X.X.X.X#33182: read
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.986 client X.X.X.X#33182: next
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.986 client X.X.X.X#33182: request failed: end of file
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.986 client X.X.X.X#33182: endrequest
06-Aug-2012 14:51:33.986 client X.X.X.X#33182: closetcp
```

But it doesn't do anything. The zone isn't updated, nor does my nsupdate change anything. I'm not sure if the file */etc/bind/primary/sub.example.com* should exist prior to the first update or not. I tried it without the file, with an empty file and with a pre-configured zone file. Without success.

The sparse information I found on the net pointed me towards file and folder permissions regarding the bind working directory, so I changed the permissions of both */etc/bind* and */var/cache/bind* (which is the home dir of my "bind" user).

I'm not a 100% sure if the permissions are correct.. but it looks good to me:

```
ls -lah /var/cache/bind/
total 224K
drwxrwxr-x  2 bind bind 4.0K Aug  6 03:13 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4.0K Jul 21 11:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind 211K Aug  6 03:21 named.run

ls -lah /etc/bind/
total 72K
drwxr-sr-x  3 bind bind 4.0K Aug  6 14:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 87 root root 4.0K Jul 30 01:24 ..
-rw-------  1 bind bind  125 Aug  6 02:54 key.public
-rw-------  1 bind bind  156 Aug  6 02:54 key.private
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind 2.5K Aug  6 03:07 bind.keys
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  237 Aug  6 03:07 db.0
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  271 Aug  6 03:07 db.127
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  237 Aug  6 03:07 db.255
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  353 Aug  6 03:07 db.empty
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  270 Aug  6 03:07 db.local
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind 3.0K Aug  6 03:07 db.root
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  493 Aug  6 03:32 named.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  490 Aug  6 03:07 named.conf.default-zones
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind 1.2K Aug  6 14:18 named.conf.local
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind  666 Jul 29 22:51 named.conf.options
drwxr-sr-x  2 bind bind 4.0K Aug  6 03:57 primary/
-rw-r-----  1 root bind   77 Mar 19 02:57 rndc.key
-rw-r--r--  1 bind bind 1.3K Aug  6 03:07 zones.rfc1918

ls -lah /etc/bind/primary/
total 20K
drwxr-sr-x 2 bind bind 4.0K Aug  6 03:57 .
drwxr-sr-x 3 bind bind 4.0K Aug  6 14:41 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 bind bind  356 Jul 30 00:45 example.com
```

Comment: Just a tip: I had the same problem. No selinux, working on one zone bot with "sERVFAIL" error on another. I solved it by removing the .jnl file that bind generates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had pretty much exactly the same issue on an Ubuntu server and it turned out to be two problems:

(1) apparmor

I don't know if the same is true for Debian, but on Ubuntu `bind9` is run with apparmor enabled. This means it is only allowed to write to certain places. The places are listed in `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named`, and it is generally advisable to stay within these directories.
You can install the `apparmor-utils` package and (temporarily) disable apparmor for bind to see if this causes your issue:

```
sudo aa-status
```

should show `/usr/sbin/named` in the list of enforced profiles. Then run

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/sbin/named
```

to put it into complain mode.

(2) zone file

Almost no manual/tutorial mentions this, but bind9 expects an (pre-)existing zone file to work properly. The `end of file` error could be caused by the fact that zone file doesn't exist yet (`/etc/bind/primary/example.com` and `/etc/bind/primary/sub.example.com` in your example).
You can simply create one like this:

```
echo "; DO NOT EDIT MANUALLY - use the \"nsupdate\" utility to prevent data loss
;
\$ORIGIN example.com.
\$TTL 86400  ; 1 day
@    IN SOA  ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
       2009074711 ; serial
       7200       ; refresh (2 hours)
       300        ; retry (5 minutes)
       604800     ; expire (1 week)
       60         ; minimum (1 minute)
       )
   IN  NS  ns1.example.com.
ns1    IN  A  <IP of your bind server>" | sudo -u bind tee /etc/bind/primary/example.com
```

Comment: I would suggest simply following the configuration schema suggested in the Debian/Ubuntu documentation (in `/usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian.gz`) instead, which places dynamic zones in `/var/lib/bind`, something which apparmor in Ubuntu is already set up to deal with without any changes. This also avoids the unorthodox setup where `named` is allowed to change files under `/etc`.

Comment: Regarding the comment at the top of the zone template, that will be expected to disappear after the file has been rewritten by bind.

Answer (score 7):

I was having very similar issues until I changed the location of where I stored my zone files.

Bind had permission to write to `/var/cache/bind`, but your zone files are stored in `/etc/bind/...`. Bind does not currently have permission to write to files in `/etc/bind/...`, so you would need to update Bind's permissions or store the zone files in a directory where Bind has the proper permissions. I will cover the simple steps to move the zone files to the directory recommended for dynamic zones (`/var/lib/bind/`).

1. Move the zone files with `mv` (likely needs to be executed as root)

   ```
   mv /etc/bind/primary/example.com /var/lib/bind/primary/
   mv /etc/bind/primary/sub.example.com /var/lib/bind/primary/
   ```
2. Update the file path in your `named.conf` configurations. In your case this means updating `/etc/bind/named.conf.local`

   ```
   zone "example.com" {
     type master;
     file "/var/lib/bind/primary/example.com";  //this line changed
     //other stuff removed for clarity
   };

   zone "sub.example.com" {
     type master;
     file "/var/lib/bind/primary/sub.example.com";  //this line changed
     //other stuff removed for clarity
   };
   ```
3. Restart Bind with `service bind9 restart`

Comment: That worked! I use Ubuntu and restart with `systemctl restart bind9` but outside of that, moving the files under `/var/lib/bind/...` made it work. Even changing the ownership of the files under `/etc/bind/...` was not sufficient. I think that `bind9` checks the path and if it starts with `/etc`, it prevents any updates.

Comment: Just wanted to mention (at least on Debian-based systems), `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` also suggests putting dynamic configs in `/var/lib/bind`, and indicates that `/etc/bind` configs should not change dynamically

Answer (score 1):

See the section in nsupdate

```
   With the -k option, nsupdate reads the shared secret from the file
   keyfile. Keyfiles may be in two formats: a single file containing a
   named.conf-format key statement, which may be generated automatically
   by ddns-confgen, or a pair of files whose names are of the format
   K{name}.+157.+{random}.key and K{name}.+157.+{random}.private, which
   can be generated by dnssec-keygen. The -k may also be used to specify a
   SIG(0) key used to authenticate Dynamic DNS update requests. In this
   case, the key specified is not an HMAC-MD5 key.
```

So if you were to reformat it into the

```
key sub.example.com. {
        algorithm HMAC-MD5;
        secret "xxxx xxxx";
};
```

form and leave that in a file it will work, or alternatively `-k K{name}.+157.+{random}.*`

Answer (score 1):

For dyndns updates BIND must be able to write to the folders used by the zones.
It seems to me that /etc is not a right place to store such information, and looking at your permissions, etc is not writable by bind.

I suggest to try the /var/bind directory, so that bind can write to it.